# Obtain the inverse Laplace transformation of $\frac{5s^3-12s^2+11s+2}{s(s-1)^3}$

Tags: laplace-transform

Solving $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\dfrac{5s^3-12s^2+11s+2}{s(s-1)^3}\right\}$

I get $\mathcal{L}[f]=3e^tt^2-4e^tt+7e^t-2$, however the options I have are

[image]

What am I doing wrong?
Is there anything wrong with the question itself?

Comment: You haven't shown us how you got your answer, so it's impossible to say what you did wrong.  I've voted to close for lack of context, but you could patch this question up by showing what you've done.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot take a picture of my work at this moment and this would take too long to write it down in LaTeX. I expand it with partial fractions and applied the Laplace transformation Properties.

Comment: I have a mistake. It was the inverse transformation. I've just edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried by myself and I found that the problem proposition has a mistake. It has to be

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\dfrac{5s^3-12s^2+11s\color{red}{-2}}{s(s-1)^3}\right\}$$

So the correct option will be

$$D.\quad 2+3e^3+t^2e^t$$

Answer (score 1):

Have you used http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html correctly?

$$\dfrac{5s^3-12s^2+11s+3}{s(s-1)^3}$$ $$=\dfrac as+\dfrac b{s-1}+\dfrac c{(s-1)^2}+\dfrac d{(s-1)^3}$$  where $a,b,c,d$ are arbitrary constants to be determined by comparing the coefficients of different powers of $s$

Comment: Yes, I applied the partial fraction method to decompose improper fraction.

Comment: (+1) Thank you very much for your effort. I found that the problem itself has a mistake. See my answer.